# Late binding for jQuery.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, deferred

I am working with a framework that uses [jQuery Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

In my code, one async operation should executed successfully so that another async operation be executed.

```
function doOperation() {

    var def2mock = $.Deferred();
    var def1 = doSomeAsyncOperation().done(function () {
        var def2 = doAnotherAsyncOperation();
    });

   return $.when(def1, def2mock);
}
```

So I put the call for the second operation in the "done" promise of the deferred of the first operation as in the example.
Now, I wrap this sequence with the function `doOperation`. The result of `doOperation` should be the join of the two deferreds of both async calls. Meaning `doOperation` succeeds if all async operations succeed and fails if any of them fail, which is exactly what [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) does.

**The problem** is that in order to create the join with `$.when`, I need both deferreds present at the time `$.when` is called. And because the deferred of the second async operation is not available at that moment, I had to find a way to create the join first, then add the deferred of the second async operation to the join *later*.

To do this, I thought I can define a new *mock* `$.Deferred` named `def2` in `doOperation`. And when the real `def2` is ready, I can somehow *link* the real deferred to the mock one, i.e. make the real one synchronize its state with mock one. The only way I found was to do

```
def2.done(def2mock.resolve)
// and 
def2.fail(def2mock.reject)
```

but I don't feel this manual linking is the right way to do it.

So please tell me if you have a better suggestion on how to do it the right way.

Comment: In fact it should be def2.then(def2mock.resolve,def2mock.reject,def2mock.notify)

Comment: Wouldn't the following do it: `return doSomeAsyncOperation().then(doAnotherAsyncOperation())` ?

Comment: without the inner quotes, maybe

Comment: @Noseratio, after having better comprehension of the concept of `.then`  and the _fitlers_ from @FelixKling, I say your suggestion does actually work. Thank you.

Comment: @HasanBaidoon, no problem. You may want to read the docs on [Q Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which is compatible with jQuery promises. I find it a very comprehensive reading material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And when the real `def2` is ready, I can somehow *link* the real deferred to the mock one, i.e. make the real one synchronize its state with mock one.

This is actually what [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) does: It returns a new promise which gets resolved/rejected when the promise returned from the passed callback is resolved/rejected.

In order to make this work with `$.when`, you have to keep a reference to the original promise:

```
function doOperation() {
  var def1 = doSomeAsyncOperation();
  var def2 = def1.then(function () {
    return doAnotherAsyncOperation();
  });
  return $.when(def1, def2);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/adZ4W/1/)

`def2` will be resolved when the promise returned by the callback is resolved, i.e. the one that `doAnotherAsyncOperation` returns.

---

But I don't think using `$.when` is a good choice here, from a conceptional point of view. You are actually executing two asynchronous functions *sequentially*, but `$.when` is used to run asynchronous functions in *parallel*.

I would just chain the function calls via `.then` and collect the responses:

```
function doOperation() {
  return doSomeAsyncOperation().then(function (resp1) {
    return doAnotherAsyncOperation().then(function(resp2) {
      return [resp1, resp2];
    });
  });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/adZ4W/)

I'd say it's clearer here that `doAnotherAsyncOperation` is executed after `doSomeAsyncOperation` and the result of both calls is available to the caller of `doOperation`.

You might have to do something similar for the fail case.

Comment: It works. Thank you. And for the first time I understand the **.then** _filters_. And for the first time I understand that when jQuery documentation state the $.when signature as "$.when( deferreds )" they actually mean _deferreds_ or _promises_.

Comment: You're welcome! A deferred object (in jQuery) is a superset of a promise. A promise alone only lets you add callbacks to it, but it doesn't let you change its state (resolve/reject). Deferred objects let you change the state of their corresponding promise. This distinction exists because [the concept of the promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_%28programming%29) is what's important, not how its state is changed. There are multiple ways to do the state change and the jQuery developers decided to name their solution "deferred objects".

Comment: Alright! .... also in your first suggestion you are providing the "doneFilter" for the "then", still, when that promise returned by the doneFilter fails, the then promise also fails. I supposed you should return the same promise for the failFilter!?

Comment: The promise returned by `.then` takes the same state as the promise returned by either the "done" or the "fail" filter. So in your case, if the promise returned by `doAnotherAsyncOperation` is rejected, `def2` will be rejected as well. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/adZ4W/2/. That's what you want, right?

Comment: Exactly. Then the one may return different deferreds in both the doneFilter and the failFilter, and whether the original deferred resolve or reject, this will make the choice of wether to consider the promise from the doneFilter or the failFilter respectively, and that latter promise will, in turn, decide which attached callbacks to be called finally, the done or fail callbacks. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with Deferred (nor do I fully understand what it does), but if you are just looking to chain operations, would something like this work?

```
function doOperation(operations) {
    var wrapper = {};
    wrapper.index = 0;
    wrapper.operations = operations;
    wrapper.onthen = $.proxy(function() {
        if (this.index < this.operations.length) {
            this.operations[this.index]().then(this.onthen);
        }
        this.index++;
    }, wrapper);
    wrapper.onthen();
}
```

Here's a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/vz6D7/2/